# How to bind a PImage to a texture in Processing using jogl (straight OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, processing, jogl

If you've loaded an image into a PImage in Processing, what's the best way to bind it to a texture using OpenGL calls? I'm not using any of the Processing rendering stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you should able to bind a `BufferedImage`.

If so you can use PImage's [`getNative()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PImage.html#getNative--) method to access the `BufferedImage`:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = (BufferedImage) loadedPImage.getNative();
```